# Get folder size on a remote server using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the folder structure and each folder size on a remote computer path. I am able to get the folder structure but the folder size returns a standard number of 901.00 KB irrespective of any folder path I specify. I can see the script is able to get the remote folder path correctly but not the file/folder size.

Here is the code that I have come up with till now.

```
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)]
    [System.String] $ComputerName,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.String] $Path
 )

function Get-FolderSize ($_ = (get-item .))  {
Process {
$RemoteServer = @($ComputerName)
ForEach($Computer in $ComputerName) {
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$length = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName { (Get-ChildItem $_.fullname -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum 
} -ArgumentList $Path
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Folder ($_.FullName)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Length ($length)
Write-Output $obj

  }
 }
}

Function Class-Size($size)
{
 IF($size -ge 1GB)
 {
  "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1GB) + " GB"
 }
 ELSEIF($size -ge 1MB)
{
  "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1MB) + " MB"
}
ELSE
{
  "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1KB) + " KB"
}
} 

Get-ChildItem $Path | Get-FolderSize | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending | Select-Object -Property Folder, Length |
Format-Table -Property Folder, @{ Label="Size of Folder" ; Expression = {Class-Size($_.Length)} }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your `ComputerName` parameter is `[String]` but it Should be an `[Array]`
2. You called the `Invoke-Command` with `$ComputerName`, you should call only one computer in the foreach loop `-ComputerName $Computer`
3. Also calling the `$_.FullName` is wrong as well
4. The Class-Size is not really needed, you can use formatting directly from the invoke-command but this is up to you.
5. and more... Check the updated script

   ```
   Param(
   [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True)]
   [Array] $Computers,
   [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
   [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
   [System.String] $Path
   )

   Function Class-Size($size)
   {
   IF($size -ge 1GB)
   {
   "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1GB) + " GB"
   }
   ELSEIF($size -ge 1MB)
   {
   "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1MB) + " MB"
   }
   ELSE
   {
   "{0:n2}" -f  ($size / 1KB) + " KB"
   }
   } 

   function Get-FolderSize 
   {
   Param(
   $Path, [Array]$Computers
   ) 
   $Array = @()
   Foreach($Computer in $Computers)
       {
       $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

   $Length = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    (Get-ChildItem $args[0] -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum

   } -ArgumentList $Path

   $Result = "" | Select Computer,Folder,Length
   $Result.Computer = $Computer
   $Result.Folder = $Path
   $Result.Length = Class-Size $length
   $array += $Result

   }

   return $array
   }

   Get-FolderSize -Computers $Computers -Path $Path
   ```

To run it:

```
.\Get-Size.ps1 -Computers Computer1,Computer2 -Path c:\windows\system32

Computer     Folder              Length 
--------     ------              ------ 
Computer1    c:\windows\system32 2.96 GB
Computer2    c:\windows\system32 3.43 GB
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you. However, how can I modify to return the size of each file inside the folder path that I specify? For ex., If i give the path as 'C:\' only, how can I get the list of folders inside C:\ and their respective size?

Comment: you welcome, the modification you ask for require more code then few lines, and SO is not a code writing service, you should try to do it yourself first, if you have a problem we here to help.

Comment: Thanks Avshalom, I was able to get the script complete as per my requirements. But your inputs greatly helped me in completing this. Marked your answer.